# cmake does not find boost 1.63.0

Tags: c++, linux, boost, cmake, cgal

I have to compile CGAL 4.10 in Linux by myself with an alternative boost installation.
I tried to *cmake* CGAL with the following parameters, however I always get error meassages related to boost:

```
cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=$Path_to_Boost
cmake -DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=TRUE -DBOOST_ROOT=$Path_to_Boost
cmake -DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=TRUE -DBoost_NO_SYSTEM_PATH=TRUE -
DBOOST_ROOT=$Path_to_Boost
```

give the error: BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR-NOT_FOUND

```
cmake -DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=TRUE -DBoost_NO_SYSTEM_PATH=TRUE -
DBoost_INCLUDE_DIR=$Path_to_Boost/boost/version.hpp
```

and variations of it give the error: Boost version: 0.0.0, CGAL needs Boost version higher than 1.48.0

Did anyone encounter similar problems with building CGAL?

Installing CGAL and Boost with *sudo apt-get install* is not an option for me I need them on a server where I do not have su rights.

Comment: What is your CMake version? Only the very new versions (> 3.7.x) recognize boost 1.63.

Comment: I updated cmake to 3.8.x, it did not fix it, i will try it now with a lower Boost version.

Comment: If updating to 3.8 doesn't fix it, I guess it is another problem

Comment: Try `-DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR=$Path_to_Boost`. Read more in https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/FindBoost.html.